# Why cast a function call with no return to void?

Tags: c++

I was reading through a code base and saw this code:

```cpp
void some_function()
{
...
}

a_type some_other_function()
{
...
(void) some_function();
...
}
```

Why is this? Some way to make the code more readable?

Comment: You have to ask the original author, because there's no way any of us could know hers or his intentions.

Comment: Probably just a unnecessary addition to ensure no warning would be issues, should the function have the [`[[nodiscard]]` attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard). This could be a habit of the author...

Comment: @fabian Suppressing compiler errors seems logical.

Comment: Some linters used to emit a diagnostic about unused return values.  Casting to `(void)` would squelch the warnings.  Those linters were treating all return types *as if* they were annotated with `[[nodiscard]`, but that was long before that annotation existed.  But for a function that returns `void` in the first place... makes no sense to me.  Habit?  Cargo cult programming?  Monkey See, Monkey Do (or Monkey C++, Monkey Doo-doo)?

Comment: That is not casting the function. It is casting the result of the function. This pattern is usually used to explicitly indicate that you don't care about the result. But in this case, the function doesn't return anything so the cast is pretty useless.

Comment: This example cast from `void` to `void`, so something doesn't add up here. @Turgut are you sure you properly transformed original code to this code example?